# Working with JSON and the fetch API

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch this JSON in my javaScript code using the fetch API:

```
{
    "posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
    ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/posts'

let posts = []

fetch(endpoint)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => posts.push(...data))


console.log(posts[0])
```

**The console.log gives me undefined on chrome's console, but if I type posts[0] on the same console I get the post object I'm hoping to get.**

I'm serving the JSON file with json-server and the .html with the vs code extension live-server.

Comment: *"I'm trying to fetch this JSON..."* That JSON is invalid. It's the *inside* of an object initializer, but it needs the outside of it (the `{}`, e.g. `{"posts: [...]}`).

Comment: However, the main issue here is that `fetch` is *asynchronous*, so `posts` is still empty as of when you log it (*later*, when the fetch completes, entries will be added to it). Also note that you're not checking `.ok`, which you need to do; details in [this post on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: The `console.log` statement is executed before `.then(data => posts.push(...data))`, you should learn about how async functions work.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder , great post.